# Apache Spark: Error while starting PySpark

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

On a Centos machine, Python v2.6.6 and Apache Spark v1.2.1

Getting the following error when trying to run ./pyspark

Seems some issue with python but not able to figure out

```
15/06/18 08:11:16 INFO spark.SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark_1.2.1/spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 45, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PySparkShell", pyFiles=add_files)
  File "/usr/lib/spark_1.2.1/spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4/python/pyspark/context.py", line 105, in __init__
    conf, jsc)
  File "/usr/lib/spark_1.2.1/spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4/python/pyspark/context.py", line 157, in _do_init
    self._accumulatorServer = accumulators._start_update_server()
  File "/usr/lib/spark_1.2.1/spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4/python/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 269, in _start_update_server
    server = AccumulatorServer(("localhost", 0), _UpdateRequestHandler)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 402, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 413, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "<string>", line 1, in bind
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
>>> 15/06/18 08:11:16 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
15/06/18 08:11:16 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
```

Comment: Sounds like you are unable to connect to the spark master. Are you running this locally in stand alone mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the logs it looks like pyspark is unable to understand host **localhost**.Please check your /etc/hosts file , if **localhost** is not available , add an entry it should resolve this issue.

e.g:

[Ip]   [Hostname]     localhost

In case you are not able to change host entry of the server 
edit /python/pyspark/accumulators.py line number 269 as below

**server = AccumulatorServer(("[*server host name from hosts file*]", 0), _UpdateRequestHandler)**